# Capture the Substring in oracle

Tags: oracle, substring

I want to search get a sub string from the following kind of string -

```
TEST-01-2019/10/10 01:01:20
```

Expected Result -

```
TEST-01
```

Basically I want to extract everything before the Date Hyphen.
How can I achieve this ? By Regular Expression?

Comment: Does the input string always look like that? I mean, how do you know where to expect the date? Could it be, for example, `test-01-1996/23/13-2019/10/10 01:01:20` (where 1996/23/23 certainly isn't a valid date).

Comment: It will be a system generated date so it has to be a valid date in YYYY/MM/DD or YYYY/DD/MM but it will be always be after the string with hyphen and starting with th year.

Comment: OK, thank you for explanation. I've posted a SUBSTR + INSTR option as an answer; have a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '^[^-]+-[^-]+')
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

This selects `TEST-01` for the input you provided.  The logic is to match:

```
^          from the beginning of the string
    [^-]+  one or more non dash characters
    -      a literal dash
    [^-]+  one or more non dash characters
```

This corresponds to the portion before the date, at least for the sample you happen to show us.

Another approach might be to regex replace off the date string, until the end of the input:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '-[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}.*', '')
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

This regex pattern matches a dash, followed by a date in the `YYYY/MM/DD` format, followed by everything until the end of the string.  It then replaces this match with empty string, effectively removing it from the input.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please provide a little bit of a detailed explanation as what both the approaches are doing

Comment: I have added descriptions about what each approach is doing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. One more thing, It can Test/01;Test-01/Test; Only definite thing is there will be a hyphen before the Date ;and the string preceding that hyphen can again have anything; -,/.
Also it can be Test-01 without any date appended. Hence I want to capture all of these records.  Any way we can modify the REGEXP_SUBSTR in that scenario?

Comment: If the hyphen + date always occurs at the _end_ of your string, and you always want to retain the earlier portion, then the regex substring option should suffice.  Otherwise, it may not.

Comment: Yes it will always happen at the end of the string. But will the regex substr work if the preceding string does not have '-'. Like it does not seem to work for the following scenarios :

TEST/01-2019/10/10 01:01:20

TEST_01-2019/10/10 01:01:20

TEST_01

Comment: Hmm, that is where I want to handle all these scenarios. Please let me know if you have any updated answers for the added requirements, Again thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A `SUBSTR` + `INSTR` option:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'TEST-01-2019/10/10 01:01:20'                  from dual union all
  3     select 'something else-goes here-2019/08/30 12:33:00' from dual union all
  4     select 'TEST/01-2019/10/10 01:01:20'                  from dual union all
  5     select 'TEST_01-2019/10/10 01:01:20'                  from dual union all
  6     select 'TEST-01'                                      from dual
  7    )
  8  select col,
  9    substr(col, 1, case when regexp_count(col, '\d+') > 2 then regexp_instr(col, '-\d') - 1
 10                        else length(col)
 11                   end
 12          ) result
 13  from test;

COL                                          RESULT
-------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
TEST-01-2019/10/10 01:01:20                  TEST
something else-goes here-2019/08/30 12:33:00 something else-goes here
TEST/01-2019/10/10 01:01:20                  TEST/01
TEST_01-2019/10/10 01:01:20                  TEST_01
TEST-01                                      TEST-01

SQL>
```

Comment: Any way I can search the hyphen from backwards and select all the preceding strings. Like if I have 
**TEST/01-2019/10/10 01:01:20** 
**TEST_01-2019/10/10 01:01:20**
**TEST_01**
All these scenarios to be selected as well ?

Comment: I've edited the query; instead of using INSTR, I've modified it to use REGEXP_INSTR, find the first "hyphen followed by a digit" and fetch everything that's in front of it.

Comment: The edited solution doesn't quite do what the OP wanted. Look at your first row: the `RESULT` should be `TEST-01`,  not just `TEST`.  Moreover, if you modify the query again to search for '-\d{4}`, the solution will fail on an input like `TEST-0101-2019/03/20 12:30:00`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below, using `regexp_replace()`, finds the pattern "dash, four digits, forward slash, two digits, forward slash, two digits, space, two digits, colon, two digits, colon, two digits", and if it is found, it removes it and all remaining (following) characters to the end of the string. It does not validate the "date" (it does not check to see that it is a valid date-time string). If the pattern is not found, then the function returns the original string, unchanged.

Note the last argument to the function, `'n'`. That is there for the (unlikely, but possible) case when the input string includes newlines. Normally the dot `.` as a wildcard character does not match newline; the `'n'` modifier changes that behavior, allowing the dot to match newline also.

```
with
  test (col) as (
    select 'TEST-01-2019/10/10 01:01:20'                  from dual union all
    select 'something else-goes here-2019/08/30 12:33:00' from dual union all
    select 'TEST/01-2019/10/10 01:01:20'                  from dual union all
    select 'TEST_01-2019/10/10 01:01:20'                  from dual union all
    select 'TEST-01'                                      from dual
  )
select col, 
       regexp_replace(col, '-\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.*',
                           null, 1, 1, 'n') as result
from   test
;

COL                                          RESULT                        
-------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
TEST-01-2019/10/10 01:01:20                  TEST-01                       
something else-goes here-2019/08/30 12:33:00 something else-goes here      
TEST/01-2019/10/10 01:01:20                  TEST/01                       
TEST_01-2019/10/10 01:01:20                  TEST_01                       
TEST-01                                      TEST-01
```

**EDIT**:  Here is a solution that uses only standard string functions, and therefore *may* be faster (and perhaps significantly so) than any solution using regular expressions.

```
select col,
       case when translate(col, '123456789', '000000000') 
                   like '%-0000/00/00 00:00:00%'
            then substr(col, 1, instr(translate(col, '123456789', '000000000'),
                                      '-0000/00/00 00:00:00') - 1)
            else col
       end  as result
from   test
;
```